# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value " ObjectId" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Contact"

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, robo3t

What I was trying to do is delete a Item from the database by using findByIdAndDelete() function and the problem that I'm running into is that
[Here is a image of the error(Please ignore all the other things)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40p4d.png)

There is also another error along side the first one showing on the terminal

[Both the errors are coming togehter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvBrD.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is a space at the start of the _id. Could it be that the _id was added manually and not auto-generated?

Comment: @masquerade817 yes that was added manually.

Answer (score 0):

there is a " " before this id, try remove it,`using id.replace(' ','')`